# Vampire short story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, vampire

My friend in high school let me borrow a book of short stories. I think Ray Bradbury was one of the writers. Maybe Isaac Asimov?

I want to read it again but I can't remember the title. 
There is a story in there that I remember.

A little boy lives with his mom or grandma who rents a room to a man that turns out to be a vampire. The kid realizes something is off about the man. The man suspects the kid is on to him and gets the boy in trouble by breaking a stained glass window and making it look like the kid did it. The kid also watches as the woman butchers a chicken which in the end plays an important role.

Comment: When was high school for you?  I.e. was this 2015, 2005, 1995, 1985, 1975, 1965, or 1955?  Do you remember anything about the book?  Color of the cover, etc.?

Answer (score 8):

Ray Bradbury "*The Man Upstairs*". It was anthologised in *The Small Assassin*, and no doubt [elsewhere](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58405).

The chicken does indeed figure in the boy's ingenious way of getting rid of the vampire, but revealing how would be an awful spoiler.

> “Anyone want more dressing?” Grandma ladled liberal portions from the chicken’s interior . . . “Then what did kill Koberman?” The coroner drew a few strands of sewing thread from the bedding. “This . . .” he said. Sunlight blinked coldly off a half-revealed treasure trove; six dollars and seventy cents worth  of silver dimes inside Mr Koberman’s chest. “I think Douglas made a wise investment.” Said the coroner, sewing the flesh back up over the  “dressing” quickly.

Comment: Also turned into an episode of his TV show "The Ray Bradbury Theater" (which is where I recognized it from after reading the question but before seeing the answer).